# <table> style elements not showing

Tags: html, css, asp.net-mvc

I'm working on an intranet, specifically on a *Report* page that can be printed out, displaying a grid with the amount of hours worked by an employee during a selected month. Here is a screenshot of what it looks like right now :

[image]

As you can tell, there isn't much separation and clarity in the display of the information.

Here is the part of the View that displays all of it :

```
  <table> 

    <tr>
        <th>Date</th>
        <th>Activité</th>
    </tr>
<%

    int total = 0;
    int i = 0;
    foreach (var jour in ViewBag.ListDaysOfMonth)
    {
        if (ViewBag.ReportInts.Length > i)
        {
            total += decimal.Parse(ViewBag.ReportInts[i]);

            if (jour.Contains("Mo") && i != 0)
            {
            %>

            <tr>
            <td colspan="2">&nbsp;
            </td>
            </tr>

            <%
            }  
            %>

            <tr>
            <td width="150"><%= jour%>&nbsp;</td>
            <td><%= ViewBag.ReportInts[i++]%></td>
            </tr>
<%
        }
        else
        {
%>
            <tr>
            <td align="center" colspan="2">Aucune activité.</td>
            </tr>
<%
        }
    }
%>
   <tr>
        <th>Total</th>
        <th><%= total %></th>
   </tr>             
</table>
```

For some odd reason, I can't make it so that the information is displayed as a grid (without any plugins, just css).

```
table
{
    border-collapse: separate;
    border-spacing: 2px;
    margin-top: 0.75em;
    border: 2px;
}

th
{
    font-size: 0.85em;
    text-align: left;
    padding-left: 0;
}
```

I'm rather new to the technology, how may I display it cleanly and separately?

EDIT :

Here is more or less what I want to have as a final display (without the background color)

[image]

EDIT2:

I have gotten extremely close to what I wanted by taking care of this tables style directly in the code (I know it's not a great idea usually). By adding `style="border:1px solid;"` where needed, a grid is displayed.

Comment: What to you mean _displayed as a grid_ and _cleanly and separately_? What do you want it to look like?

Comment: I have added a picture

Comment: Then just add borders etc in your css - e.g. `td { border: solid grey 1px' }`

Comment: Well isn't it already there? (As shown in the code) Am I missing something?

Comment: I have changed the content of `table` in my css file to what you have shared, still, nothing. Is there something I should include in order to apply the effect?

Comment: Refer [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xr0thjqs/) for an example

Comment: Thanks to your help and some research I have found a solution. (c.f edit)

Comment: You should not be using inline styles - your clearly have some other issues with your css files which you should be fixing instead

Comment: Absolutely, that's what I'm doing right now. At least I know the attributes I'll use in my css file once the issue is fixed. I'm on it. Thank you !

Answer (score 0):

You have only specified the width of the border in your CSS file. You should also specify the border-style attribute, in order to display it.

For example:

```
border: 1px solid black;
```

The color (black in my example) is optional, but you may specify it together with the other properties using the shorthand.

See also [this MDN article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/border) on specifying borders in CSS.